# How do I install plugins on PocketMine without a computer?

Tags: minecraft-bedrock-edition, minecraft-bedrock-edition-server

On PocketMine.com, I went to the plugins zone and found plugins I want for my upcoming MCPE server (il post IP on profile when done).

But, I don't have a computer to use, so I need to do this without a computer.

I have not yet installed the PocketMine app, but I will install it soon if this is possible to do.

Can I just use my tablet for installing plugins with the website and the app, or do I need a file storing app (ie: Dropbox)

Devices used:

Tablet: iPad 4 running 8.1.1 (I DON'T want 8.2)

PocketMine plugins and app to latest version.

Comment: Regarding the VTC: asking *how* to install mods for Minecraft is not the same as asking for technical support for modded Minecraft.

Answer (score 1):

Also, pocketmine-MP can only be installed on the following devices:

- **Android Device,**
- **Windows computer,**
- **linux,**
- **Mac OSX,**
- **Jailbroken iOS Devices,**

Unfortunatly, without Jailbreak you cannot install Pocketmine-MP, sorry. You can create a free 24 hour server at instantmcpe.com

But you cannot get plugins.

Comment: Instead of adding another answer, please edit things into your previous answers.

Comment: Sorry, i'm new here and didnt see the 'edit' button at first.

Comment: No worries! Just edit one of your answers into the other, and delete the obsolete one.

Answer (score -1):

a new no jailbreak application get out named "**Plug Pocketmine**"
You can actually run a Pocketmine server right from your iOS no jailbreak device :)
Its supports plugins from www.pocketmine.net but you cannot modify configuratiob and you cant upload your own plugin